# not showing apps in software center

Tags: software-installation, software-center, 16.04

I'm  new to Ubuntu and installed  16.04 LTS but in software center all application is not showing only showing those software which is already  install to my system

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to select the *All* window, and use the search feature to find the program(s) you consider to install.

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html

Comment: I'm  just  opening software  and start typing   but    no application found  is  showing

Comment: @aayushharsh: Sounds strange. You may want to open a terminal window and run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to make sure you have the latest version of all packages. (But I have never heard of this problem before.)